# Android-Editable Expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to create something like [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/) but I want the user to be able to add to the list and I want them to be able to edit the items. I am a beginner so please don't hate. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very generic question. How can we help you without us to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to have to build a custom one since editable items isn't something supported directly in the default items. What you need to do is look at listview adapters and create a custom layout for each item which maybe a textbox. Then you need to handle it (like allowing them to enter text and disabling the editing via your own methods. Might want to start by looking into this: http://goo.gl/8HKmxO

Comment: thanks. but it seems a little too complicated. anything that is simpler to understand?

Comment: Not that I know of, Sorry :(